# On click of text view application note responding

Tags: android, textview, android-cardview

I am using `cardView` and inside that `textView` for showing data.`OnClick` of this `textView` application crush.

**.xml file is**

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/spcard_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/spthumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sptitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:minLines="3"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/album_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/album_title"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spthumbnail"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spcount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sptitle"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/spoverflow"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spthumbnail"
              android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_margin_top"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dots" />
         </RelativeLayout>
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/spdetailsbuynow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="buy now"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/spdetailsbutton"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/spdetailsaddcart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="add cart"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/orange_500"/>
</LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And the error log is

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method true(View) in a
>   parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on
>   view class android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: Post your java code

Comment: You should post the relevant code and also the logcat.

Comment: please be more clear. Are you trying to click on a textView and if yes, which one in your layout? Or do you want to click on a button and a text should appear on the textView? Also, please show how you have implemented it in your java class.

Comment: Please add full error log of logcat.

Answer (score -2):

```
use like this:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/off_white_bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/spcard_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spthumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sptitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:minLines="3"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/album_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/album_title"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spthumbnail"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spcount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/sptitle"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spoverflow"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/spthumbnail"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_margin_top"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dots" />
     </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/spdetailsbuynow"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="buy now"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/spdetailsbutton"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/spdetailsaddcart"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="add cart"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/orange_500"/>
</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try explaining  what this is for and what to change , posting code don't help

Comment: please show how you have implemented it in your java class patel?